# Labeling within tex document

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

[image]I was wondering if anyone knows how to properly use or implement the following labels in a tex file. I know you would type `•‹label›` but can't seem to find a good reference for it.

Comment: do you mean a bullet list? `\begin{itemize} \item aaa \item bbb \end{itemize}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No not quite. I forgot to attach a picture of what I mean.

Comment: It is still not that clear what you want, but I assume the markup is as in my first comment but you want to specify the item label as `\textbullet ‹Problem›` which you could easily specify using `enumitem`